# Change color when scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been looking a solution for this but I couldn't get it to work.

I would like my page header to change from a transparent background to a red background as the user begins scrolling the page.

```js
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() > 800) {
        $(".header").addClass("active");
    } else {
       $(".header").removeClass("active");
    }
});
```

```css
* {margin:0;padding:0}

html {
    background: lightgray;
    height: 5000px;
}

.header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 10000;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    height: auto;
    background-color: rgba(17, 42, 107, 0.7);
    
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
}

.header.active {
    background: red;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">the header</div>
```

Comment: Your snippet is spitting out errors

Comment: The `style` and `script` tags don’t belong into the snippet, and jQuery needs to be added. I was trying to edit your snippet for you, but as soon as I do that – it works; so in that case it would be unclear what you are asking about to begin with.

Comment: After editing your snippet to work (no style / script tags where they don't belong and included jQuery), your code seems to work as you want it to work?

Comment: is working for me, what's not working?

Comment: I'm using firefox browser?

Comment: its working fine. I'm such an idiot, didn't refresh the page after saving the work, sorry in advance.

Comment: Then how to apply it by vanilla java script?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    console.log(scroll);
    if (scroll >= 10) {
        $(".header").addClass("active");
    } else {
        $(".header").removeClass("active");
    }
});
```